# ¿como recorrer una array con typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

tengo un JSON que contiene multiples datos los que necesito editar,
mediante typescript encontre que puedo modificarlo mediante map

```
his.items =  this.items.map((item: string) =>
```

ahora dentro de item tengo una ruta item.better_featured_image que contiene un objeto pero aveces contiene solo null, quiero modificarlo y agregar la ruta faltante. pero al parecer estoy en un error ya que la ruta al ser null ya no es un objeto

```
this.items =  this.items.map((item: string) => {
     if(item.better_featured_image == null){
      let item.better_featured_image = {}; 
      item.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url = 'logo-web-color.png';



     }

     return item;
     });
```

json completo aqui http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a4a315a4c3c1ce08471541fdf8bc1a10

mi idea es crear la ruta faltante en el objecto que contenga null

Comment: Podrias  agregar el contenido de JSON ?

Comment: @marcogomes ahi agregue el json

Comment: estas usando angular ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que estás usando `let`, declarando una variable, cuando lo que querés editar es un atributo del objeto, además falta definir los atributos que se hacen falta para llegar a al atributo `source_url`, tu código funcional quedaría así:

```
this.items = json.map((item) => {
     if(item && !item.better_featured_image){
          item.better_featured_image = { 'media_details': {'sizes': {'thumbnail': {'source_url': null}}} };
          item.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url = 'logo-web-color.png';
     }
     return item;
});
```

Ya que estamos hablando de la imagen, podrías simplificar las cosas dejando un solo atributo:

```
this.items = json.map((item) => {
     if(item && !item.better_featured_image){
          item.better_featured_image = { 'source_url': 'logo-web-color.png' };
     }
     return item;
});
```

[Acá](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20json%20%3D%20JSON.parse('%5B%7B%22better_featured_image%22%3A%7B%20%22id%22%3A%201%7D%7D%2C%7B%22better_featured_image%22%3A%7B%20%22id%22%3A%202%7D%20%7D%2C%7B%22better_featured_image%22%3Anull%20%7D%5D')%0D%0A%0D%0Ajson%20%3D%20json.map((item)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20if(item%20%26%26%20!item.better_featured_image)%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20item.better_featured_image%20%3D%20%7B'media_details'%3A%20%7B'sizes'%3A%20%7B'thumbnail'%3A%20%7B'source_url'%3A%20null%7D%7D%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20item.better_featured_image.media_details.sizes.thumbnail.source_url%20%3D%20'logo-web-color.png'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20return%20item%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(json)%3B) te dejo la muestra funcional! Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Saludos!